# How to use git to work with a file with two different sources

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have a software project with two parts. In the first part, I am working to convert some ancient files from waterloo script to xml. The second part is to convert that xml into SQL commands that I can use to create a database to run a website.

I have written a parser that takes the old files and has created an "ent.xml" file that is mostly correct. It looks okay but it works better after I do some manual editing on it. In addition, I add updated information that is needed to complete the project.

However, I occasionally find that my parsing had an error and I need to fix the parser and recreate the "ent.xml". But this will often cause conflicts with the manual editing I've done on the same file.

I would like to use git to handle these conflicts. It has a good conflict management system and I feel I can use that to merge the changes and make both sides happy.

I thought I would create a "parser" branch and make all changes to the parser there. I would continue to use the "master" branch to make manual edits to the file. I would then merge "parser" with "master" after I fix a parser error.

The issue then becomes what to do with the next parser error? After the merge, the "parser" branch should effectively be the same as the "master" branch. Isn't it? Basically I want two different source to both edit the same file on an ongoing basis.

Can I keep making changes to the "parser" branch with its unedited "ent.xml" and merge it multiple times into the "master" branch? Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: For me this would depend on the type of changes you make and how the expected collisions would look like. The method you describe would cause annoying collisions unless you only make a few manual changes and changing the parser would also only change a few lines. In similar cases I have written an sed (or awk) script to do the "manual editting". I greatly oppose myself to put ANYTHING generated in a git repository and that is solved like that too: you just generate your xml file with the parser and then run your sed script over it. In another case I wrote a special new tool to do the merging.

Answer (score 0):

First or all, `git` is not intended to be used that way I'm afraid. In the long run, the best solution would be to write some code wich merges your input files.

Anyways, here is a possible `git` solution. I understand you want to keep your branches with the manual and the parser edits separated.

You could create 3 branches:

```
parser # here you will update your parser edits
manual # here you will update your manual edits
result (or maybe master) # you can merge both parser and manual in here
```

You can now freely edit your `parser` and `manual` branches, and if needed, merge the results into `result` or `master`.